# Infinite Scroll and Masonry jquery plugin - ways to make it load earlier and faster

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, scroll, infinite-scroll

I'm using infinite scroll with django pagination on the site, 
is there a way to make it load the next page when the user scrolls down to maybe 2/3 of the page? Infinite scroll seems pretty slow at loading everything all at once when posts have images.

Edit:

didn't know why bufferPx wasn't working well. Now I'm thinking it's probably because I'm using it along with Masonry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try increasing the bufferPx in the infinite scroll options when calling the function. see here for more options:

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did try that before without much success. I'm now thinking, it's probably because I'm using it with Masonry, darn.